# How to intercept the call to a service method in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to intercept a call to a Service method and execute some code before it.

For example, someone wrote:

```
$this->container->get('file_locator')->isAbsolutePath($path);
```

I want to intercept the call to **Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator::isAbsolutePath()** and execute some code before it.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can leverage tag 'priority' option to make sure your service is called before other, but those tags are available to kernel event listeners only. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: I don't want to intercept the call to container->get('service_id') but to intercept the call to the method from that service

Comment: Simply, no. Not without modifying his code. If you can modify the code you could add an event callout to the beginning of it then add an event subscriber and run your code when that event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to achieve exactly what you are looking for, but I can think of two methods that you should be able to use to achieve the same effect:

And then you have two options:

### 1. Override service

You could override the service with your own service which extends default one and overrides isAbsolutePath() method.

Override default `FileLocator` class with your own:

```
class MyCustomFileLocator extends FileLocator
{
    public function isAbsolutePath()
    {
        // Your awesome code here...
        return parent::isAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

And override service definition:

```
# services.yml

# Just create a new definition with the same name

services:
    file_locator:
        class: MyCustomFileLocator
        arguments: [...]

# Or alternatively, if you're overriding one of symfony/third bundle services, 
# they often provide class parameter which can be overriden

parameters:
    file_locator.class: MyCustomFileLocator
```

### 2. Decorate service (Symfony >= 2.5)

You can use [service decoration techinque](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services), which will yield the same effect, but you will still have reference to original service as `file_locator.inner` if you need that for some reason.

Comment: Decorating service is exactly what I was looking for.